# Undefined is not a function error when using axios

Tags: php, symfony, reactjs

I have Web application written in symfony and I am using ReactJS server and client side rendering.
First I developed it in localhost, after I transported it into server, everything kinda broke.

Now i have a question, how should i know or where should i look error in my code.

Look at [SERVER] errors.

Error here:
[image]
What generates my error:
[image]

If i comment out axios get request, no error

Comment: Seems like `response.data` is `nil` while setting `related state`.

Comment: impossible, i disabled server side rendering and it works perfectly, the URL is just an example.
I have debugged everything, `response.data` is `{data: []} || {data: [ .... ]}`
I even tried only `axios.get('/sample/data')` same error

Comment: I'm not sure if you've already done this, but have you checked the logs in the `var/logs` folder to see if that shows more information? I would also suggest using the debug URL `app_dev.php` appended to your main URL; you make get more useful messages.

Comment: well, my apache serves app_dev.php from /. problem im facing with server side rendering, is that phpexecjs library is broken or .... i dont know, i just disabled server side rendering and im fine with that, it was kinda useless anyway.
There are render errors too, they are kinda wtf errors, routes and components are exactly the same, but different rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good chance that your localhost was running a more up-to-date version of node JS than the server that you migrated your app to.  I had the same issue -- **axios** was failing with a useless `[TypeError: undefined is not a function]` until I upgraded.  Try using nvm:

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

That way you can upgrade node JS and keep close track of which version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was an error, due to wrong import.
Use:

```
import axios from "axios";
```

instead of:

```
 import { axios } from "axios";
```